# Need software that can generate user reports by selecting items from an ER Diagram

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, reporting

I've spent the last few days looking into Reporting Services - Report Builder 3.0 and BIDS Report Designer.  The Report Designer seems to do most of what I need, except that it doesn't have one key feature - I want to enable my end users to generate reports by selecting tables and columns from something like an Entity Relationship diagram.

I noticed when I was creating a Report Model for my reports that the 'Data Source View' that I create as part of creating the report is almost exactly what I am looking for - it even has a 'Diagram Organiser' so that I can group my tables logically.  But there doesn't appear to be any way within BIDS or Report Builder to view a Data Source View (or equivalent), let alone use it to select the required fields for the report.

Is there any tool out there (preferably but not necessarily one that generates reports that are compatible with SSRS) that can do what I want?

Answer (score 1):

Your users should use Report Builder to customize reports.

Report Designer = BIDS, for developers. On BIDS, you will create the report models the users will work with  on the report builder. A report model is a metadata description of a data source and its relationships. Report models provide familiar business names for database fields and tables, logically grouped model items, and predefined relationships between items within the data source.

Comment: I understand what you say, but within Report Builder there doesn't appear to be a way to visualise those pre-defined relationships, as it simply provides a text-based list of available tables.  If for example TableA is related to TableX only via 4 intermediate tables then that is instantly obvious from an ER diagram, but from within Report Builder using a Report Model as a data source it would require intimate knowledge of the database (or a print-out of an ER Diagram generated elsewhere) to have any chance of selecting data from those two tables.